# AutoMapper 6.0.2 - How can initialization performance be increased?

Tags: performance, automapper

There are many performance discussions around AutoMapper out there.
I have the issue, that the initialization just takes too much time, even though I don´t have a very big model compared to other applications. It is the following code block that matters:

```
        var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
          {
            cfg.CreateMap<..., ...>();
            cfg.CreateMap<..., ...>();
            // ... I have (just) 100 calls to cfg.CreateMap here...
          });
```

Until yesterday I used version **5.0.2** and then I updated to the current stable version **6.0.2**. This alone brought me some 25% faster initialization. But that is not enough. On a server of one customer this section takes about 8 seconds. We work with several worker processes, so every time such a process starts, it takes 8 seconds more again. That is not acceptable.
I tested also with the use of AutoMapper-Profile-classes. It didn´t make any difference.
Is there any way to postpone some part of the initialization nearer to the moment where mappings are actually needed for the first time?
Thanks everybody for your ideas!
:-)

Comment: Could you estimate the complexity of your mappings? Do you have deep nested maps?

Comment: Can you open an issue on GitHub? We have solutions with a very large number of mappings (100s) but don't see this slowdown.